# ESRI maps giving Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread in iOS 11

Tags: multithreading, maps, ios11, esri-arc-engine, esri-maps

I'm using ESRI maps in my application. When i run the application in iOS 10 there was no issue in loading the ESRI maps, zoom in and out works fine too. But when i run the same application with iOS 11 it gives me

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication 
applicationState]
PID: 485, TID: 72091, Thread name: Runtime Network Callback Thread, Queue 
name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   Altus Mobile                        0x00000001006f4844 -
    [AGSRequestOperation kickoffConnection] + 1108 .  
5   Foundation                          0x0000000185987a50 <redacted> + 340
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184f40358 <redacted> + 24
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184f402d8 <redacted> + 88
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184f3fb60 <redacted> + 204
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184f3d738 <redacted> + 1048
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184e5e2d8 
    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
11  Foundation                          0x00000001858866e4 <redacted> + 304
12  Altus Mobile                        0x00000001007dbf28 -
    [AGSThreadTargetImpl mainRoutine] + 292
13  Foundation                          0x0000000185987860 <redacted> + 996
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184bc432c <redacted> + 308
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184bc41f8 <redacted> + 0
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184bc2c38 thread_start + 4
    2017-10-26 13:11:41.375952+0530 Altus Mobile[485:72091] [reports] Main 
Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication .   
applicationState]
```

I know Apple has enable the Main Thead Checker in Latest Xcode version which tells if we use any UI Main Thread in background. Just to make sure the issue is with ESRI Maps have commented the loading part of ESRI maps, main thread checker issue didn't popped up, but when i uncommented it back, issue back again. Also when i zoom in and zoom out the ESRI map i'm getting

```
 2017-10-26 13:11:41.659743+0530 Altus Mobile[485:72060] Task <504051EF-9770-
 4852-AFB8-C47DF112DA52>.<30> finished with error - code: -999
```

Did anyone faced similar issue with ESRI maps? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you come up with a resolution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was facing the same issue with ArcGIS SDK version **100.0.0** in iOS 11. Upgrading the ArcGIS SDK to **100.1.1** solved this issue for me.